# Using a predicate to find all rows?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following code, I am using the repository pattern in EF 4.1 and Unit of Work.
However because I dont understand very much how Expression and Predicates works I ask the following:

With the code below, is there a better way to find all rows?

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var positions = unitOfWork.PositionRepository
                                  .Find(p => p.PositionID != null);

        return View(positions.ToList());
    }
```

I based my UnitofWork and Repository from here
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I tried this:

```
public virtual List<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return context.Set<TEntity>.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all rows you simply have to call this on your set:

```
context.Positions.ToList();
```

So simply add method to your repository exposing this result.

In case of generic (wrong) repository use this:

```
context.Set<Position>().ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, why would it be wrong to use a generic repository? I think it makes the code cleaner and easier to use from the controllers.

Comment: please see the edit. that code does not compile in the generic repository, what am I missing?

Comment: Because there is nothing like generic repository. Generic repository is just useless wrapper around EF classes and it solves nothing. Repository (the one described by pattern) is specific and expose entity specific methods.